Error when adjusting the volume of an audio tag with a range slider
I get Uncaught DOMException: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount when adjusting the volume of an  tag with a range slider.
I tried using this code:
function ppayVolume(){
        var volSlider = document.getElementById("volume");
    var realplayerEL = document.getElementById("real-player");
    var volVAL = document.getElementById("volume").value    
    realplayerEL.volume = volVAL
    console.log(volVAL)


But it will not work and show an error.

Update: problem solved! using a range of 0 to 1 worked!

The error you're encountering, Uncaught DOMException: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount, typically occurs when you're trying to set the volume property of an HTML <audio> or <video> element to a value outside the valid range, which is between 0.0 and 1.0.
You need to scale the value of your slider from 0-100 to 0.0-1.0 before setting it as the volume.
function ppayVolume(){
    var volSlider = document.getElementById("volume");
    var realplayerEL = document.getElementById("real-player");

    // Get the slider value (assuming it's 0-100)
    var volVAL = volSlider.value;

    // Scale the value to 0.0 - 1.0
    var scaledVolume = volVAL / 100;

    // Set the volume, ensuring it's within the valid range
    realplayerEL.volume = Math.min(Math.max(scaledVolume, 0.0), 1.0);

    // Optional: Log the scaled value
    console.log(scaledVolume);
}

